Flutter Realm can two changelisteners run parallely causing race conditon?
I am creating my realm instance in my App Singleton class, and from there wherever I need to execute any realm query I use that singleton class's realm object to execute it. Now as my realm instance is created in the background thread, I am calling two query changelisteners in my initState method of my screen, now I want to confirm can these two changelisteners be invoked parallely so that it can cause a race condition or not? Because I want them to call not asynchronously relative to each other.

Dart is single-threaded - you can't have multiple callbacks execute in parallel, regardless of whether using Realm or pure dart.

But as my change Listeners are invoking in background ground how can you be  so sure that only one single background thread will invoke them? Thanks for Helping :)

Dart is single threaded, so as long as you're not spawning different isolates, your change listeners will never invoke in parallel, even if the change calculation happens on a background thread. One callback will always execute first, complete, then the other callback will be invoked.
